# how do I change the default program hat opens an file

Tags: c#, file-extension

I have created a program that opens image files. How can I make my program from C# the default app for image file's (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the install/setup package-makers should do this for you.

From Visual Studio you can use the included "Setup Package" project type (located under "Other Project Types"). Right-click on the setup project you created in your solution, and select "view > file types" and you can setup whatever file types you'd like on the client's machine, and how to open them.

InstallShield and all of the others also support this stuff too.